# Finding the Minimum Distance Traveled

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We Are giving N cities and Q Travel Queries which are executed in Order , To Travel Between 2 cities it takes i-j time , We are having 2 Cars. We have to find the minimum time taken by the Cars for traveling.
For Example

```
5 4 // 5 cities and 4 Query
1 5
3 2
4 1
2 4
First Using Car-1 Time= 5-1=4 sec
Then Using Car-2  TIme = 3-2= 1 sec
Then Using Car-1  Time = (5-4)+(4-1)= 4 sec
Then Using Car-2  TIme = (4-2)= 2 sec
Total Time = 11 sec
```

I could not think of a dynamic programing solution that maintaining a state

```
dp[i][j][k] i=0 or 1
          j = postion of Cars
          k = After k Query
```

Could you provide me idea about dynamic programing for this.

Comment: Interesting question, but it feels very much like a competition question.  If you can give a link to a competition that's already finished, I'll answer, otherwise I will in a few days.

Comment: What is the initial position of the cars? Is it a must to use both 2 cars at least once?